# MFC when to render a custom control

Tags: c++, mfc, custom-controls

I have a control subclass (displaying a graphical editor) that works fine, except I don't know where to do the initial call to draw itself.  It re-renders itself in response to mouse events so as soon as you mouse over it, it is in order.  I can't call the function to render it from the ctor as the `m_hWnd` doesn't yet exist, but memory fails me as to where I DO call that function.

Based on some old code that worked fine but for various reasons didn't have to do an initial render, my class is subclassed from `CButton`.  I forget why I did that on the old controls, but it doesn't seem to be a problem.

"Works fine" means: getting mouse and keyboard events, resizing, showing that it's lost focus, handling constant display updates with various editing tools and cursors and rendering the data as it's being edited etc.  Stable, shuts down cleanly as far as I can tell, etc.

Calling the rendering method from the parent dialog's `OnInitDialog()` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Any control, when initially shown, receives a `WM_PAINT`message. It is unclear, why you aren't rendering in your `WM_PAINT` handler, or indeed how your control works at all. Sounds like you are performing something fishy.

Comment: Pls see edit, @IInspectable

Comment: Don't explain, what your code does. Provide a [mcve] instead.

Comment: Put your WM_PAINT suggestion as an answer and I'll mark it as such.

Comment: I'd rather not answer an incomplete question. The expected ROI is not enough of an incentive to do so. Post a [mcve] and make this Q&A valuable to future visitors.